# How do i host HTML in Silverlight 4.0 (Out of Browser)?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have to host HTML in Silverlight 4.0 Only for Out of Browser Application.

How i do that?

Please Give me Solution.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: I don´t understand your question. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

you should note that only Out-of-Browser applications support the WebBrowser control, 
and if you try to use it in an in-browser app, it will not display anything.
 so add this WebBrowser tag to your xaml page.

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="wbFrame" Source="http://www.stackoverflow.com" />
```

or if you want to use a html tag ,you can use the property **NavigateToString** of **WebBrowser** Class in the code behind;

```
wbFrame.NavigateToString("your html text");
```